# Initialise a Django multiple file field form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a django form defined as:

```
class FileFieldForm(forms.Form):
    file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

When I load this form in my views I'm using:

```
file_form = FileFieldForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')
    if file_form.is_valid():
        for f in files:
            m = MyImages (
                 image = f,
                 item = item
            )
            m.save()
```

I now want to initialise the form with those files in it and allow the user to change, delete, update the files.

My questions are:
1. How do I initialise the form in this case?
2. How do I check if they're changed when the user resubmits?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can check using checksums that file is changed or not. You just have to compute the checksum once and store it in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to initialise the form so I used the queryset instead and displayed them like this:

```
            <label for="id_file_field" class="btn-abysm center">Upload Images</label><br>
                {{ file_form.file_field }}
                <div id="result" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                    {% for f in myimages %}
                        <span><img class="image-thumbnail" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag{{ forloop.counter }}" src="{{ f.image.url }}" ></span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
```